# Regex issue in PHP (extracting digits)

Tags: php, regex

What's a quick way for matching the following in a multiline string using `preg_match`?

```
id=334534534
```

`id=` is constant. The digits are what I need to extract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regexp'll be something like this: `/id=(\d+)/im`

Where the `/` are the reg exp delimitators, the `i` means "case insensitive" and `m` means "multi-line".

With [preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) you can do this:

```
$subject = "YOUR STRING HERE";
$pattern = '/id=(\d+)/im';

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```